# jsonArray not showing (web service)

Tags: c#, json, web-services

Methode in web Service

Methode :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)] 
public void GetList()
{
      JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

      Test[] test=new Test[3];
      test[0] = new Test("1", "anex");
      test[1] = new Test("2", "Ahmed");
      test[2] = new Test("3", "Karim");

      var json = new
      {
          list=test ,
          DateTime=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()                             
      };

      HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ser.Serialize(json)); 
}
```

Result : `{"list":[{},{},{}],"DateTime":"03/10/2016"}`

List not showing !!

Comment: Please add the definition of the ´Test´ class. If it has no properties or only private ones, then the Serializer will ignore them.

Comment: public class Test
    {

        private string id { get; set; }
        private string name { get; set; }

        public Test() { }
        public Test(String i, String n)
        {
            this.id = i;
            this.name = n;
        }
    }

Comment: thanks @rboe it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Test` class does contain private fields only. Therefore the `JavaScriptSerializer` will ignore them. Declare them as `public` an they will show up in the produced JSON.

Comment: @Ane'xBm - You are welcome. Please don't forget to mark the post as answer if it has answered your question.